# Unable to install pip on windows 10 with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am on Windows 10 with Python 2.7 installed. I installed pip following instructions [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows):

I also see following message at end of installation:

> Successfully installed pip-20.3.4

But when I do 'pip help'(in a new command prompt), I see:

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

What else is needed to get it working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Answer (score 0):

Manually add pip path to env variable PATH. Pip is installed at location C:\Python27\Scripts.